# parallelize a list comprehension with multiple inputs python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, list-comprehension, osmnx

I have a big dataset that needs to return a value, however when running it takes ages (I run the list comprehension with progress bar) therefore I was thinking of parallelizing the list comprehension. However, when running it on a small sample it takes longer than the original list comprehension.

This is my list comprehension it will return the osmnx nearest node

```
%%time
origins=[ox.get_nearest_node(G, (y[i], x[i])) for i in pbar(list(range(len(buildings))))]
```

This is the multiprocessing I already tried with origins as a function with params (G,y,x). Buildings is a dataset that contains the geometry of all buildings.

```
x = [buildings.geometry[i].centroid.y for i in list(range(len(buildings)))]
y = [buildings.geometry[i].centroid.y for i in list(range(len(buildings)))]
params = ((G, orig, dest) for orig, dest in zip(y, x))

def origins(G, x, y):
  return ox.get_nearest_node(G, (y, x))

#create a pool of worker processes
pool = mp.Pool(3)

#map the function/parameters to the worker processes
sma = pool.starmap_async(origins, params)

%%time
#get the results, close the pool, wait for worker processes to all exit
routes = sma.get()
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Can someone help me parallelize my list comprehension that makes my process faster

Comment: On a small sample it will always take longer in parallel, because you have the additional overhead of spawning the processes. Think of it like a break-even calculation. With multiprocessing, your initial cost is higher but the processing speed is faster. Therefore, you need a sufficient amount of processing so that it is worth investing the initial overhead.

Comment: Possibly, the serialization and transfer of data to the processes take more time than the computation itself. You can try using `G` as a global variable in `origins` and get a sense if that's the direction.

Comment: Please provide 1) code timings for the various parts and 2) a complete, minimal, reproducible code snippet that allows us to fully reproduce your problem (several variables are currently undefined). https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example